# Yii: How to validatePassword with Edvlerblog\Adldap2 using userprincipalname instead of samaccountname

Tags: yii2, ldap, adldap

#### Question

Currently looking for how other people handled the validate password function when they need to authenticate with the `userprincipalname` instead of the Edvlerblog\Adldap2 validatePassword function which uses `samaccountname`.

> Please provide feedback in the comments if you are struggling with
>   anything specific so we can update the documentation.

#### Current Implementation

For `app/common/model/LoginForm`

**getUser**

The Edvlerblog\Adldap2 getUser() function works, and even caches the queryLdapUserObject, allowing you to fetch any of the AD attributes.

```php
protected function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === null) {
        $this->_user = \Edvlerblog\Adldap2\model\UserDbLdap::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

**validatePassword()**

Currently, the following validatePassword function does not work for me because in my instance AD must authenticate against the `userprincipalname` instead of the `samaccount` name.

```php
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A solution

Here is one workaround thanks to the Edvlerblog\Adldap2 who recently released 3.0.5 addressing a couple issues and providing some examples in his readme docs.

Please note the addition of findByAttribute(), allowing the following:

```
 $this->_user = \Edvlerblog\Adldap2\model\UserDbLdap::findByUsername($this->username);
```

**validatePassword() w/ userprincipalname**

Update your login model: `common\models\LoginForm.php`

```php
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            $this->addError('username', 'Incorrect username.');
        } else {
            // Note: queryLdapUserObject is a cached object, 
            // so the ldap fetch does not get called :-).
            $userprincipalname = $this->_user->queryLdapUserObject()->getAttribute('userprincipalname');
            $auth = Yii::$app->ad->auth()->attempt($userprincipalname[0], $this->password);
            if (!$auth) {
                $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect password.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**getUser()** w/userprincipalname

```
    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = \Edvlerblog\Adldap2\model\UserDbLdap::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
```

**Yii2 ldap Component Configuration**

Reference:  https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

Config in your `frontend\config\main`:

```
'components' => [
        'log' => [... ],
        'authManager' => [... ],
        'ad' => [
            'class' => 'Edvlerblog\Adldap2\Adldap2Wrapper',
            'providers' => [
                'default' => [
                    'autoconnect' => true,
                    'config' => [
                        'domain_controllers' => ['your.ldap.domain.com'],
                        'base_dn'            => "OU=XXX,OU=XXX,DC=ccccccc,DC=xxxx,DC=com",
                        'admin_username'     => "your_username",
                        'admin_password'     => "your_password",
                        'port'               => 389,
                    ],
                ],

            ],

        ],
    ],
```