# Yii2 Ldap implement kosoukhov/yii2-ldap

Tags: yii2, ldap, yii2-advanced-app

I am newbie with Yii2 and I need to create a login system using ldap. There is not much information about it so I hope somebody can help me.

I installed kosoukhov/yii2-ldap but don't know how to implentment it from that.

I tried editing my code as below but cannot login.

LoginForm.php

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }




    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {

           if (!Yii::$app->ldap->validateUserCredentials('SAMAccountName', 'password')) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username LDAP or password.');
            }

    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        }

        return false;


    }

    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you!

Comment: So I prefer the yii2 extension Edvlerblog\Adldap2:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266547/yii-how-to-validatepassword-with-edvlerblog-adldap2-using-userprincipalname-ins

Comment: what route did you end up going?